# When must you use <- instead of = in R

Tags: r, coding-style, variable-assignment

This is an issue that's perplexed me and my students for years now, and I realise now that others have been asking the same question. My stock response for recommending `<-` assignment (e.g. in my [Introduction to Visualising Spatial Data in R](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/blob/master/intro-spatial-rl.pdf)) has been that "that's what R developers use and we trust them".

But when Yihui Xie, an eminent R developer, [advocates `=`](http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/a-few-notes-on-user2014/), I'm no longer sure.

Is that a sufficient reason? The best reason I've seen so far for favouring `<-` is that "mathematicians would be confused by `x = x + 1`, but not `x <- x + 1`". Fair enough but most mathematicians I know can also understand programs that use `=` for assignment. (Reference: comments under here http://alyssafrazee.com/introducing-R.html )

The other reason is that `=` is used for arguments in functions, so `<-` should be used in function calls. But what are the precise contexts in which `=` will fail? And is there not an advantage of reserving `<-`/`->` for situations where it's really needed, such as:

In a function:

```
system.time(x <- rnorm(10e6)) 
system.time(x = rnorm(10e6)) # error
system.time({x = rnorm(10e6)}) # no error
```

Right hand assignment:

```
library("dplyr")
data_frame(x = 1:26, y = letters) %>% 
  filter(x %% 3 == 0) %>% 
  top_n(n = 3, wt = x) -> df
df
```

Comment: _Possibly_ you may find additional relevant info in any of the [33 questions currently linked to the dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1741820?lq=1)

Comment: Woops - thanks for pointing that out and apologies for not checking before posting.

Comment: "_not checking before posting_"? Disregarding the fact that you _should_ search before posting, I am puzzled that you find it faster to compose a (nicely formatted) SO question than googling "R assignment operators" (the official name of `<-` in its help text)...;)